# A way to render multiple root elements on VueJS with v-for directive

Tags: components, vuejs2

Right now, I'm trying to make a website that shows recent news posts which is supplied my NodeJS API.

I've tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="news" class="media" v-for="item in posts">
    <div>
        <h4 class="media-heading">{{item.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.msg}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const news = new Vue({
    el: '#news',
    data:   {
        posts:  [
            {title: 'My First News post',   msg: 'This is your fist news!'},
            {title: 'Cakes are great food', msg: 'Yummy Yummy Yummy'},
            {title: 'How to learnVueJS',    msg: 'Start Learning!'},
        ]
    }
})
```

Apparently, the above didn't work because Vue can't render multiple root elements.

I've looked up the VueJS's official manual and couldn't come up with a solution.
After googling a while, I've understood that it was impossible to render multiple root element, however, I yet to have been able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can have multiple root elements (or components) using [render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function)

A simple example is having a component which renders multiple `<li>` elements:

```
<template>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item2</li>
 ... etc
</template>
```

However the above will throw an error. To solve this error the above template can be converted to:

```
export default {
 functional: true,
 render(createElement) {
  return [
    createElement('li', 'Item'),
    createElement('li', 'Item2'),
  ]
 }
}
```

But again as you probably noticed this can get very tedious if for example you want to display 50 li items. So, eventually, to dynamically display elements you can do:

```
export default {
 functional: true,
 props: ['listItems'], //this is an array of `<li>` names (e.g. ['Item', 'Item2'])

 render(createElement, { props }) {
   return props.listItems.map(name => {
     return createElement('li', name)
   })
 }
}
```

**INFO** in those examples i have used the property **functional: true** but it is not required of course to use "render functions". Please consider learning more about functional components[here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components)

Comment: Old question but I'd just add that this rule is going away in Vue 3. In Vue 3 you can have multiple root elements in plain old components.

Comment: In Vue 2 this does not work.  Even with a custom render function I get: `[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.`

Answer (score 32):

The simplest way I've found of adding multiple root elements is to add a single `<div>` wrapper element and make it disappear with some CSS magic for the purposes of rendering.

For this we can use the "display: contents" CSS property. The effect is that it makes the container disappear, making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM.

Therefore, in your Vue component template you can have something like this:

```
<template>
    <div style="display: contents"> <!-- my wrapper div is rendered invisible -->
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </div>
</template>
```

I can now use my component without the browser messing up formatting because the wrapping `<div>` root element will be ignored by the browser for display purposes:

```
<table>
   <my-component></my-component> <!-- the wrapping div will be ignored -->
</table>
```

Note however, that although this should work in most browsers, you may want to [check here](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Acontents) to make sure it can handle your target browser.

Comment: That's not multi-root. That's just wrapping it into a single root.

Answer (score 10):

Define a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
Vue.directive('fragments', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    const children = Array.from(el.children)
    const parent = el.parentElement
    children.forEach((item) => { parent.appendChild(item) })
    parent.removeChild(el)
  }
});
```

then you can use it in root element of a component

```
<div v-fragments>
  <tr v-for="post in posts">...</tr>
</div>
```

The root element will not be rendered in DOM, which is especially effective when rendering table.

Comment: This does not appear to handle reactivity at all.  The `update` directive event does not appear to fire when children are added/removed/moved either, making it impossible to use this for a reactive example.

Answer (score 5):

Vue requires that there be a single root node.  However, try changing your html to this:

```
<div id="news" >
    <div class="media" v-for="item in posts">
       <h4 class="media-heading">{{item.title}}</h4>
       <p>{{item.msg}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This change allows for a single root node id="news" and yet still allows for rendering the lists of recent posts.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question Ron! It has worked!!!

Comment: Excellent.  Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark by the answer. Thanks, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3):

In Vue 3, [this is supported](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html#_3-x-syntax) as you were trying:

> In 3.x, components now can have multiple root nodes! However, this does require developers to explicitly define where attributes should be distributed.
>
> ```html
> <!-- Layout.vue -->
> <template>
>   <header>...</header>
>   <main v-bind="$attrs">...</main>
>   <footer>...</footer>
> </template>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple root elements are not supported by Vue (which caused by your `v-for` directive, beacause it may render more than 1 elements). And is also very simple to solve, just wrap your HTML into another Element will do.

For example:

```
<div id="app">
   <!-- your HTML code -->
</div>
```

and the js:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', // it must be a single root!
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a reasonable solution when you MUST have two root elements. Such as the case when a component library requires such a configuration. A problem even AngularJS tacked successfully with their `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` ages ago.

Comment: Imagine if your root element is a `tr` as well, html specifies that putting div (or any other tag than thead, tbody, tr, tfoot) inside a table tag is not allowed