# Use a component to render each Vuetify expansion panel item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to using Vuetify's `v-expansion-panel` component (AKA accordion) to render one panel for each task in a list. The parent component's template is:

```
<div v-if="tasks.length">
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <task
      v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
      :task="task"
      :key="index"
    />
  </v-expansion-panels>
</div>
```

Then the child `task` component renders the content of each panel like so:

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel>

    <v-expansion-panel-header>
    <!-- render panel header content -->
    </v-expansion-panel-header>

    <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <!-- render panel body content -->
    </v-expansion-panel-content>

  </v-expansion-panel>
</template>
```

It's convenient for me to render the header and body in a single component, because they largely depend on the same data. However, I don't like the way that the markup for the expansion panels is split over two different components. Because of this, if I unit test the child `task` component I get a warning:

> [Vuetify] The v-expansion-panel component must be used inside a v-expansion-panels

Is there a way I can move all the expansion panel markup into the parent component, but generate the content for `v-expansion-panel-header` and `v-expansion-panel-content` in the child `task` component?

Comment: Ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add all expansion panels together and in task.vue do the v-for?

```
<task :tasks="tasks" />
```

Task.vue

```
 <template>
    <v-expansion-panels 
      <v-expansion-panel
         v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
         :task="task"
         :key="index">>
    
        <v-expansion-panel-header>
        <!-- render panel header content -->
        </v-expansion-panel-header>
    
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
        <!-- render panel body content -->
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
    
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
    </template>
```

Comment: Because then I'd have to manage the data for all tasks in a single component, which would be very messy

Comment: Really I cannot understand your concern. Having a component which renders a task is considered as best practice. Even if for unit testing you can mount the component and test it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple root elements in Vue 2 using render functions. It is more tricky to use but it would work. Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52182744/13165683).

Alternatively, you can use the `vue-fragment` component (link to [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment)) that does it for you like so:

```html
<template>
  <fragment>
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
    <!-- render panel header content -->
    </v-expansion-panel-header>

    <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <!-- render panel body content -->
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </fragment>
</template>
```

Comment: I already have a single root element in both components